# Understanding the numpy's conversion of datetime64 to int64

Tags: python, numpy

I have a an array containing some `dates`:

```
import numpy as np

dates = np.arange('2005-01', '2005-12', dtype='datetime64[M]')

print(dates)

['2005-01' '2005-02' '2005-03' '2005-04' '2005-05' '2005-06' '2005-07'
 '2005-08' '2005-09' '2005-10' '2005-11']
```

When I do:

```
dates.astype(np.int64)
```

I get:

```
array([420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430])
```

What are these numbers? I specifically want to know whether every year-month has a unique code like these?

I read [Datetimes and Timedeltas](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html) but I could not find any information about how `numpy` converts `datetime64` to integers.

Comment: ```dates.astype(np.int64)``` is simply reporting the number of months since the date 1970-01.

Comment: Does this mean every year-month combination has a unique integer value?

Comment: yes, assuming every month's difference from 1970-01 is unique.  I can't imagine it would be otherwise.